# Angular 7, named router outlet doesn't work inside lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

So I faced with the famous angular routing problem ["named outlet with lazy loaded module"](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981). This issue seems to be closed and [this guy provided a plunker](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981#issuecomment-454425220) with working solution, which I've been following. However I still getting an error and can't understand the nature of this problem

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

I've tried to use pathMatch: 'full' with different redirection routes to different components but in the end always got the same error.

I'm stuck already on couple hours, that's why decided to ask question here. Where is my problem and what I'm missing?

My setup

app.routing.ts:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule',
      },
      {
        path: 'admin',
        loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
      },
      {
        path: 'data',
        loadChildren: 'app/data/data.module#DataModule',
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: ''
      }
    ];
```

app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

data.routing-module.ts

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'summary',
    component: SummaryComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'management/:id',
    component: DataComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'activities',
        component: ActivitiesComponent,
        outlet: 'activities',
      },
      {
        path: 'researches',
        component: ResearchesComponent,
        outlet: 'researches',
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'review/:id',
    component: InfoComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
];
```

data.component.html

```
<mat-drawer-container class="docs-viewer-container">

  <mat-drawer position='start' [mode]='mode'>
    <router-outlet name="activities"></router-outlet>
  </mat-drawer>

  <mat-drawer position='end' [mode]='mode'>
    <router-outlet name="researches"></router-outlet>
  </mat-drawer>

  <mat-drawer-content>
    ... 
     // content
    ...
  </mat-drawer-content>

</mat-drawer-container>
```

So landing page for data module is summary component after user clicked link to navigate url route looks like so :`'path/data/summary?params'`. Summary.component has navigation function

```
  onActivitySelection(event) {

    this.queryParams.offset = 0;
    this.queryParams.limit = 25

    this.router.navigate([{
        outlets: {
          'activities': '/data/management/' + event.id + '/activities'
        }
      }],
      {
        queryParams: this.queryParams
      })
  }
```

As you can see redirection route must be '/data/management/:id/activities'. But error says that this route cannot be find.

So could anybody help me with my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try housing the module's routes in an index component. You have a router-outlet for the app module, but not any of the levels below it.

For data module's routes:

```
{
    path: '', component: DataIndexComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
       path: 'summary',
       component: SummaryComponent
      },
      ...[restOfRoutes]
      ]
}
```

Within the DataIndexComponent add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

On another note, if you're using the same auth guard, you can place it on the module's index level.

Comment: Just before your comment, I've tried to apply similar solution and it works particially. 
IndexComponent.html:
 `<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="activities"></router-outlet>`
So if I manually provide url angular redirects me to necessary route, but it is not working if I try to navigate with function `onActivitySelection(event)`. Seems something wrong there...

Comment: I personally wouldn't put a router-outlet underneath the main one as you're meaning to append the rest of the routes after 'data' as according to the Url Tree, not having the child router-outlet adjacent to the App router-outlet. Try `this.router.navigate([\`/data/management/${eventId}/activities\`])`. 

(P.S. I don't think there's a need to explicitly name the outlets of the children routes if you have no intention of adding children underneath it.)

Comment: ... or if you follow the nesting pattern of the router-outlets.

Comment: I replaced name outlet to child component because it seems right, but `this.router.navigate([`/data/management/${eventId}/activities`])`

Comment: I don't think you finished your comment. It seems you didn't add back-ticks to the argument within the array. Show me the replacement or can you put it in a Stackblitz.